# Git infinite loop

Tags: git

Stuck on a git infinite loop following the instructions of the git command line.  If I am already up to date, why can't I push. It's asking me to pull. So I pull.  I'm already up to date. I need to push my stuff.

```
$ git push
trace: built-in: git 'push'
trace: run_command: 'ssh' 'git@somewhere' 'git-receive-pack '\''rt.git'\'''
Enter passphrase for key '/blah/blah':
To git@somewhere:rt.git
 ! [rejected]        BRANCH-1600 -> BRANCH-1600 (non-fast-forward)
 ! [rejected]        release_1.0.1 -> release_1.0.1 (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@somewhere:rt.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.


$ git pull
trace: exec: 'git-pull'
trace: run_command: 'git-pull'
trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '--git-dir'
trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '--is-bare-repository'
trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '--show-toplevel'
trace: built-in: git 'ls-files' '-u'
trace: built-in: git 'symbolic-ref' '-q' 'HEAD'
trace: built-in: git 'config' '--bool' 'branch.BRANCH-1600.rebase'
trace: built-in: git 'config' '--bool' 'pull.rebase'
trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '-q' '--verify' 'HEAD'
trace: built-in: git 'fetch' '--update-head-ok'
trace: run_command: 'ssh' 'git@somewhere' 'git-upload-pack '\''rt.git'\'''
Enter passphrase for key '/home/achen/.ssh/id_rsa':
trace: run_command: 'rev-list' '--verify-objects' '--stdin' '--not' '--all' '--quiet'
trace: run_command: 'rev-list' '--verify-objects' '--stdin' '--not' '--all'
trace: exec: 'git' 'rev-list' '--verify-objects' '--stdin' '--not' '--all'
trace: built-in: git 'rev-list' '--verify-objects' '--stdin' '--not' '--all'
trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '-q' '--verify' 'HEAD'
trace: built-in: git 'fmt-merge-msg'
trace: built-in: git 'merge' 'Merge branch '\''rel_3.6.0'\'' of somewhere:rt into RTDE                                                 V-1600' 'HEAD' '6ba69b1fc5973ecbc5cef61a3846a901ca82c17a'
Already up-to-date.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$ git co BRANCH-1600
$ git pull
$ git push
```

and same to `release_1.0.1` branch.

Or you can delete `BRANCH-1600` & `release_1.0.1` branches in remote repo first.

```
$ git push :BRANCH-1600
$ git push :release_1.0.1
$ git push -u origin BRANCH-1600
$ git push -u origin release_1.0.1
```

I guess you've rollbacked some commits (or commit with `--amend` arg), but you've already push them to remote repo before.

If you're sure that the source of your local branch is the right one, just push it to remote forcibly with `-f` arg:

```
$ git push -f origin BRANCH-1600
$ git push -f origin release_1.0.1
```

Comment: I just did the git co (checkout) of the branch and it says i'm already on BRANCH-1600.  Doing the git pull and git push yields the same results (expected).  Part of the workflow here is to use Gitlab and I can't just delete or remove repositories at will.  Especially not the release branch on Gitlab.

Comment: @user1855069 try to push with `-f` arg if you're sure that the source of your local branch is the right one. See the new version of my answer. :)